# Magento: Is possible to show in place of "Not available" to show ex. "Comming in 2-4 days"

Tags: product, out-of-stock

In the product list or in the product page is this possible to replace the `Not available` text when the product is `out of stock` with something like "Coming soon in 2-4 days" ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change.

Go to your `template/product/view/type/default.phtml` and change the text as you require.

Sometime some theme have this file in different place, so you might want to have a look in to your `/layout/catalog.xml` to find which `phtml` file is responsible for this.

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            ............................
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

Also in `<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>`, `<PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>` and `<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy way is to translate the word `out of stock` on `Comming soon in 2-4 days`.
Go to your backend and enable `translate inline for frontend`. And make the change on frontend.

For more details about translation click on [this link](https://www.joomlart.com/tutorials/magento-tutorials/magento-tutorial-how-to-enable-inline-translation).